# Convert c# binding object based on the system.ServiceModel

Tags: c#, wcf

Can anybody help me create a binding object in C# based on the configuration provided below. This is copied from app.config of the project where my wcf service is referenced.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="BindingName">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
            requireDerivedKeys="true" includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
            <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://example.com/test.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingName"
        contract="Service.IService" name="BindingName" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   var config = new BindingElementCollection();

        TransportSecurityBindingElement transportSecurityBindingElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();

        transportSecurityBindingElement.IncludeTimestamp = true;
        transportSecurityBindingElement.MessageSecurityVersion =
            MessageSecurityVersion
                .WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
        transportSecurityBindingElement.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;
        transportSecurityBindingElement.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = false;
        transportSecurityBindingElement.LocalServiceSettings.DetectReplays = false;
        transportSecurityBindingElement.SetKeyDerivation(true);

        config.Add(transportSecurityBindingElement);
        config.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, Encoding.UTF8));
        config.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());

        return new CustomBinding(config);
```

Comment: Please be sure to give people an up vote when something is correct, it helps the rest of us find correct solutions. :-)